# Using CSS to Make This Theme Fit Browser Window

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm trying to create a site using this theme - http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-4-col-portfolio/

It's already responsive, but instead of images, I'd like them to be rectangle boxes that are links, and which, depending upon the size of the user's browser window, will always expand or contract to fit the browser window, with about 20px margin in between each one, evenly-spaced throughout.

Have no knowledge of Javascript, but am wondering if this can be done with CSS.

What I'm wanting is kind of like Chris Coyier's example here - https://css-tricks.com/examples/SeamlessResponsivePhotoGrid/, but need each rectangle to be evenly spaced and sized in the theme preview above.

Thanks for your help!

Oh, and if anyone knows how to Wordpressify it, that would be incredible!

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of it, the site you provided uses the meta veiwport tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
```

But the tag only works well if your CSS sizes are %'s instead of pixels. (including font sizes)

Comment: and for the spacing, you can use padding in your CSS(again using %'s not pixels)

Comment: could you post a snippet of your CSS?

Comment: It's using Bootstrap, which is a responsive framework created by Twitter.  So, it's all responsive and uses different %'s depending upon breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It can do by using css3 calc() you can change size of you images parent div using calc dynamically

change your

```
<div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
```

to `<div class="asd">`

and add style like this

```
.asd{
    width: calc(80%/4);
    float:left;
    margin:2%;
}
```

## Live Demo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Do you happen to know how compatible that solution is across browsers?  For the @media declarations in the CSS file for .container, I was able to get it to work by making the container width 100%.

Comment: I think you want to change size according to browser window size (like my solution ) am I correct ? calc cross browser compatibility : http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Yes, your solution works, but as the browser window size decreases (for mobile users), I wouldn't want 4 rectangles viewed horizontally, but stacked on top of each other.  So, I guess I could specify different calc for each @media query...

Comment: your theme is worked like you said.. don't you want images ? you want linked divs when you click on div want to navigate somewhere else ?

Comment: Yeah, no images.  Want to use just CSS for the rectangles, and they will link to another page when user clicks on them.